# Date localization in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I need help with date localization in laravel. Actually, I need to display format as `YYYY-MM-DD` if user choose EN language, and for others I want `DD.MM.YYYY`. Right now I use if statement to determine the selected language and render the page based on that.

```
@if(App::isLocale('en'))
    <p>{{date("Y-m-d", strtotime($t->StartofBreak))}}</p>
@else
    <p>{{date("d.m.Y", strtotime($t->StartofBreak))}}</p>
@endif
```

This is a bad solution in my opinion since I have a lot of pages with date fields, and for each of them I need to use this. Any way to improve this?

Comment: Laravel uses Carbon for the date formatting, so check out what the Carbon docs say about [localization](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-localization)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple solution is to use translations or config to define date formats for each langages.

In /ressources/lang/en/app.php :

```
'date_format' => 'Y-m-d'
```

Set it for each language.

Then use :

```
<p>{{ date(__('app.date_format'), strtotime($t->StartofBreak)) }}</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with **ternary** condition
 like this

```
 <p>{{date((App::isLocale('en'))?"Y-m-d":"d.m.Y", strtotime($t->StartofBreak))}}</p>
```

Comment: This works as well, but I prefer @Vincent Decaux solution. But thank you!